# How to record user's voice from the website but without Flash?

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, html

How to record user's voice from the website without Flash? I want to use HTML5 but I found it will be hard to implement that. [This site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) says this functionality is now only supported by the latest version of Chrome and Opera.

After searching the articles both here and the other site, I decide to find an alternative approach.

The scenario is: users will use different sort of platform (Android/iOS and other OS), but they access the same website and record their voice in their device and upload it later.

BTW: My purpose is that, as the users press the "Record" button on my web-page, the recording starts with his microphone. And as he presses the button again, the process stops. This can be on an iPad or a mobile phone so that he can't record his voice by some other software and store in his device then upload. They use their device to link my web-page to record voice. The webpage is not just for the users who operate on a PC.

Can I implement this function in client side via javascript? Or I should refer to Server side? What language and method should I adopt?

Comment: if only thing you want is for them to record their voice on device and upload later, why can't you use just file upload ? m i missing something here, your scenario suggested this only.

Comment: Thank you for your remind! My purpose is that: as the users press the "Record" button on my web-page,the record starts.(with his microphone). And as he presses the button again, the process stops. Thus I get his voice. And what's more, it is on an iPad or a mobile phone so that he can't record his voice by some other software and store in his device then uploading. They use their device to link my web-page to record voice. The webpage is not just for the users who operate on a PC.

Comment: Presumably on most smart-phones/tablets, a user can record something using an app, generate a local audio file, and upload to a website? This may not be non-optimal for you, but you seem to be saying that this isn't possible. Is that really the case?

Comment: Maybe the user don't have to record the file in their device.
But I must get their voice in my server so that I can play it.

Comment: Dear Halfer:
    I can't let the users to install any APP. It's not allowed. The scenario is that the users owns different OS can press the record button on the web-page then get their voice recorded. Is this possible? If not, maybe I have to reconsider the scenario.

Comment: The record functionality is still under construction...
I have to let the client to communicate with server...

Answer (score 2):

You can check google's web fundamental article on recording audio here : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/

Its pretty easy to follow and it is device independent, obviously given correct browser support. You can get the audio recorded and saved on the local device or upload it to a server. Hope it helps.

oh, and on a note, its based on HTML5 and js. I don't know why you think implementing it using HTML5 is difficult but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it was up to me, I'd go for something like the link mentioned above and just use a fallback to Flash applet if its not supported in the users browser.

When it comes to the mobile platform, you'll have a big problem at least with the iPhone. I dont think you can upload files, and Iam pretty certain that you cannot record audio from their microphone. The best approach would be an application to do such a thing on mobile devices. Iam pretty sure that this can be done with PhoneGap - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html

If your not familiar with PhoneGap it allows you to write cross platform applications for mobile devices in HTML/CSS/JS and still get access to some core components. Like capturing audio.

Comment: N...Sorry Steffen... Did you say: "not familiar with PhoneGap,and it allows me to xxxxxx"? Do you mean: If I "were familiar "with PhoneGap, and it would allow me to ......?
Just wanna make sure~

And thank you for suggestion. I will start to use PhoneGap for the work immediately to try to address the issue. 
But I still need someone's suggestion since I don't know this would work or not...

Comment: Hehe, yeah I meant if your didn't know what PhoneGap is. As I said, I havent tried this out myself, so Iam not a hundred percent sure how to do it.
Keep in mind that you'll need a Developer Account at Apple in order to publish your app to the AppStore (99$/year).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you can't record from the browser, however, if you have an app (you can use Phonegap/Cordova (which use HTML5, JS and CSS to build your app for many platforms)) to record whatever you want to record, you can easily upload what you want to your server. It is currently impossible to use pure HTML5 in the mobile web browser to do this.

If you want to learn more about this, the API reference is a good start: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio